# count Internet data usage in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, internet

I am using a Broadband connection which provides me greater speed with Limited usage as 2.5 GB per Month.

I want some application which can help me by counting my data up/down volumes everyday , so that I can control my usage & stop getting extra bill for over usage.

is there any application like that ?